# "Climbed and tried to" or "climbed and try to"

Tags: verbs, sequence-of-tenses

> 1. I climbed the ladder and try to grab the fruit.
> 2. I climbed the ladder and tried to grab the fruit.

I was taught that if the first verb is a past tense, the 2 verb that follows should be in simple present tense. Is this collect?

Answer (score 5):

> "I climb**ed** the ladder and tri**ed** to grab the fruit."

is correct.

That sentence is composed of two parts, and each part can be turned into a sentence by itself:

> "I climbed the ladder."
>
> "I tried to grab the fruit."

If you are talking about the past, both sentences need to be in the past tense, and when you connect them with "**and**", both verbs should be in the past tense.

++++

*However*, the second sentence by itself ("I tried to grab the fruit.") actually has a compound verb ("tried to grab"). In this two-part combined verb, only the first part ("tried") is in the past tense. The second of the two parts ("to grab") remains in its infinitive form. [This reference](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-verbs-and-infinitives/4085937.html) explains about the verb **try** when it has a complementary *second* verb attached.

If someone was explaining that, "if the first verb is a past tense, the 2nd verb that follows should be in ..." some *other* form, ... I wonder if that explanation might have been about the phrase "tried to grab" rather than about the entire sentence. (Just a speculation.)

Comment: *... and would/will try to grab* would be wrong?

Comment: "I will try to grab the fruit" *by itself* is fine. It's a statement in the future tense. But, "I climb**ed** the ladder and **will try** to grab the fruit." mixes past and future tense. If that is really what you are trying to say (I have *already* climbed the ladder [past], and *now* I am going to try to grab the fruit [future]), then I guess the sentence is not *wrong*, but it sounds kind of strange because we wonder why you are describing this simple action with so much slow-motion detail. ... [to be continued]

Comment: "I climb**ed** the ladder and **would try** to grab the fruit." has both verbs past tense. Strictly speaking this sentence is correct. You climbed the ladder (past) and wanted/wished to try for the fruit (also past). But this sentence too, sounds a little strange and maybe antique to me, because we don't use "would" in quite that way any more. Sorry to be so detailed and picky/pedantic, but I don't want to give you false information.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate your detailed comments. To me it's very useful to see how a native speaker of English thinks. Btw, +1.